# Is it possible to replace maya geometry cache with alembic cache?

Tags: maya, alembic

I am researching the way to improve efficiency of using cache in Maya. For wide use, **Alembic Cache** is a good choice as I know. So, I try to use it as replacement of **Geometry Cache**(mcx). But **Alembic Cache** has a limitation of matching names of targets. On behalf of **Geometry Cache**, is there any aid for using **Alembic Cache**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered this in a previously asked question.

### To overcome the non-matching name target problem:

When you import the abc file into Maya, it creates an abc Node in the Maya scene. If the object name doesn't match your scene's object name, you can connect it manually.

The way you do this is as follows.

[image]

The alembic node has a bunch of output plug Arrays, like `outPolyMesh`, `outNSurface` etc. These contain the outputs. If your render object is a mesh, you will be able to find the corresponding output plug inside the `outPolyMesh` array. In your connections editor, just connect the corresponding `outPolyMesh[i]` plug into your `inMesh` plug of your render model's shape node.

Hope that was useful.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. But I have a question about it. If there is no name-matched geometry, I can't generate a alembicNode with __Import Alembic__ menu. How can I create just a alembicNode with abc file?

Comment: In the import options dialog, there's a setting to include non matching nodes. Just check that on. To locate this node, open your outliner.. Go to display.. Uncheck show dag only. Now in the search box, type in the regex `*_abc_*` and the alembic node will be shown.

Comment: I meant that I hope to import just a alembicNode without geometries :) I will try to use that option.